# Calculating statistics with pure SQL queries

Tags: sql

The SQL table consists of columns `calling_party`, `called_party` and `call_duration`. The example records are the following:

```
A,B,23
A,C,12
A,H,90
B,R,56
N,B,78
```

For every user that is stored in both roles as `calling_party` and `called_party` I would like to make statistics, for example what was the total duration of incoming conversations, what was the number of outgoing conversations etc.

To select users I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t1.calling_party
FROM 
    dbo.monthly_connections AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT called_party 
     FROM dbo.monthly_connections) AS t2 ON t1.calling_party = t2.called_party AS table_users
```

From here on I know how to create a method in a chosen programming language that goes through all returned rows and performs a query for each row:

```
SELECT SUM(call_duration), COUNT(*)
FROM table_users
WHERE calling_party = current_user
GROUP BY calling_party
```

If it is possible I would prefer to write a nested query that would calculate the statistics for every user without the help of custom method written in programming language but don't know how to do it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, but your queries confuse more than they clarify. For instance, does `table_users` really have columns called `call_duration` and `calling_party`? It would help a lot if you documented the table definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
WITH INCOMING AS (
  SELECT called_party PARTY, SUM(call_duration) INCOMING_TOTAL
    FROM monthly_connections
   GROUP BY called_party
),
OUTGOING AS (
  SELECT calling_party PARTY, SUM(call_duration) OUTGOING_TOTAL
    FROM monthly_connections
   GROUP BY calling_party
)
SELECT COALESCE(INCOMING.PARTY,OUTGOING.PARTY) AS PARTY,
       INCOMING.INCOMING_TOTAL, OUTGOING.OUTGOING_TOTAL
  FROM INCOMING
  FULL OUTER JOIN OUTGOING ON OUTGOING.PARTY = INCOMING.PARTY
```